# Know when each element have same CSS property value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a form using some circles to show the user whether the field is correctly filled or not.

I want to be able to know when all of the circles are green to then change the SUBMIT button background-color.

If you didn't understand just run the snippet full screen and you'll see.

```js
// Système de toggleBox



var toggleCanvas = document.getElementById('newsteller');
let n_state = true;

function toggleNewsteller() {
  if (getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('newsteller')).backgroundColor == "rgb(180, 223, 180)") {
    n_state = false;
  } else {
    n_state = true;
  }

  if (n_state == false) {
    document.getElementById('newsteller').style.backgroundColor = "hsl(120, 3%, 93%)";
  } else if (n_state == true) {
    document.getElementById('newsteller').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(180, 223, 180)";
  }

}

function blur_check(id) {
  var element_base = document.getElementById(id);
  var circleSibling = getCircle(element_base);

  if (getComputedStyle(circleSibling).backgroundColor == "rgb(237, 238, 237)") {
    circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(180, 223, 180)';
  }
  if (element_base.value == "") {
    circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  }
}

function characters_check(sample) {
  var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "@", ";", ":", "/", "+", ")", "&", "(", "?", "!", "-", "_", "%", "*", ":", ";", "`", "^", "$"]
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (sample.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function passwordBlur() {
  var element = document.getElementById('mdpbis');
  var circleSibling = getCircle(element);

  if (getComputedStyle(circleSibling).backgroundColor == "rgb(237, 238, 237)") {
    circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  }
}

function email_check() {
  var circleSibling = getCircle(document.getElementById('email'));
  var emailString = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var arr = ["@"]
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (emailString.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
      var arr = ["."]
      for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (emailString.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
          circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(180, 223, 180)';
        } else {
          circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
        }
      }
    } else {
      circleSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
    }
  }
}


function getCircle(elements) {
  while (elements = elements.nextSibling) {
    if (elements.className === 'circle') {
      return elements;
    }
  }
  return false
}

function prenom_confirmation() {
  var prenom = document.getElementById('prenom');
  var circleStyle = getCircle(prenom).style;

  if (characters_check(prenom.value) == true) {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  } else {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = "rgb(237, 238, 237)";
  }
}

function nom_confirmation() {
  var nom = document.getElementById('nom');
  var circleStyle = getCircle(nom).style;

  if (characters_check(nom.value) == true) {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  } else {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = "rgb(237, 238, 237)";
  }
}

function username_confirmation() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username');
  var circleStyle = getCircle(username).style;

  if (characters_check(username.value) == true) {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  } else {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = "rgb(237, 238, 237)";
  }
}

function email_confirmation() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var circleStyle = getCircle(email).style;

  if (characters_check(email.value) == true) {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = "rgb(237, 238, 237)";
  } else {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 127, 123)';
  }
}

function mdp_confirmation() {
  mdp_check()
  var mdp = document.getElementById('mdp');
  var circleStyle = getCircle(mdp).style;

  if (characters_check(mdp.value) == true && mdp.value.length >= 6) {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = 'rgb(180, 223, 180)';
  } else {
    circleStyle.backgroundColor = '#FFE68D';
  }
}

function mdp_check() {
  var mdp = document.getElementById('mdp');
  var circleMdp = getCircle(mdp);
  var mdpbis = document.getElementById('mdpbis');
  var circleMdpbis = getCircle(mdpbis);

  if (mdpbis.value == mdp.value) {
    circleMdpbis.style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(circleMdp).backgroundColor;
  } else if (mdpbis.value !== mdp.value) {
    circleMdpbis.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(237, 238, 237)";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: anatialised;
}

::selection {
  background: wheat;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: #DEDEDE;
}

input:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.login-form-window {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.window-header {
  background: wheat;
  color: hsl(120, 3%, 30%);
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.window-info {
  padding: 10px;
  color: hsl(120, 3%, 60%);
}

.description {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: hsl(120, 2%, 20%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-des {
  color: hsl(120, 3%, 35%);
  margin: 10px;
}

.padding-right {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.form_col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 1px;
  text-align: right;
}

.text-input {
  border: none;
  background: hsl(120, 3%, 93%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: -2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.circle {
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: hsl(120, 3%, 93%);
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.select-country {
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: hsl(120, 3%, 93%);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(180, 223, 180);
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.checkbox,
.submit-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit-button {
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: hsl(120, 3%, 93%);
  font-size: 19px;
  color: hsl(120, 3%, 30%);
}

.submit-button::selection {
  background: none;
}

#text::selection {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="login-form-window">
  <p class="window-header">CREER UN COMPTE</p>
  <p class="window-info"><a>Samedi 5 Mai</a><a style="float:right">Formulaire d'Inscription</a></p><br>
  <form id="form">

    <label class="description form_col" id="sex">Sexe:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="H" class="radio-input" checked="1"><label class="input-des padding-right">Homme</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="F" class="radio-input"><label class="input-des padding-right">Femme</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="O" class="radio-input"><label class="input-des">Autre</label><br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Prénom:</label>
    <input id="prenom" type="text" name="prenom" value="" oninput="prenom_confirmation()" class="text-input prenom" autocomplete="given-name" onblur="blur_check('prenom')">
    <canvas class="circle"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Nom:</label>
    <input id="nom" type="text" name="nom" value="" oninput="nom_confirmation()" class="text-input nom" autocomplete="name" onblur="blur_check('nom')">
    <canvas class="circle" id="nom"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" oninput="username_confirmation()" class="text-input username" autocomplete="username" onblur="blur_check('username')">
    <canvas class="circle" id="username"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" class="text-input email" autocomplete="name" onblur=" email_check()" style="width:200px;">
    <canvas class="circle" id="email"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Mot de passe:</label>
    <input id="mdp" type="password" name="mdp" value="" oninput="mdp_confirmation()" class="text-input mdp" autocomplete="new-password" onblur="blur_check('mdp')">
    <canvas class="circle" id="mdp"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Mot de passe (confirmation):</label>
    <input id="mdpbis" type="password" name="mdpbis" value="" class="text-input mdpbis" autocomplete="new-password" oninput="mdp_check()" onblur="passwordBlur()">
    <canvas class="circle" id="mdp-bis"></canvas>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Pays de résidence:</label>
    <select class="select-country" name="country">
      <option value="">France</option>
      <option value="">Belgique</option>
      <option value="">Suisse</option>
      <option value="">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="">États Unis</option>
      <option value="">Allemagne</option>
      <option value="">Pays-Bas</option>
      <option value="">Norvège</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <label class="description form_col">Newsteller:</label>
    <canvas class="checkbox" id="newsteller" onclick="toggleNewsteller()"></canvas><br><br>

    <label class="description form_col"></label>
    <div class="form_col submit-button" id="newsteller" onclick="">SUBMIT</div>

    <br><br>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: instead of adding inline style, consider adding classes ... and then test if all the inputs have this class [by the way we don't see what you already tried to do]

Comment: One common method for validation is to set a boolean flag at the start of the routine to true then flip it to false if any field fails validation. At the end, check the flag - if it's still true, submit the form

Comment: Checking the colors is a bad idea; you should use an internal data structure to store validity; and use that to determine both the circle colors and the entire form's validity: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zu0t73ud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through each circle and check it's background-color value like this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.circle'); // get all circle elements
var y="";
x.forEach(circ => { //loop through each circle to check bg-color
    if (circ.style.backgroundColor !== 'rgb(180, 223, 180)') {
        y += '0';
    } else {
        y += '1';
    }
});

if ( y.indexOf("0") > -1 )  { // are there red circles?
    console.log('dont do anything'); //yes there are
} else {
    console.log('run submit button css change function'); // no there aren't. go ahead and run a function to change submit css here
}
```

---

However, as **@TemaniAfif** mentioned, I would suggest you add the background-color for green to a css class say, `green` and red then toggle them like this:

```
if (emailString.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
    circleSibling.classList.add('green');
    circleSibling.classList.remove('red');
} else {
    circleSibling.classList.add('red');
    circleSibling.classList.remove('green');
}
```

And replace the first snippet above with this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.circle'); // get all circle elements
x.forEach(circ => { //loop through each circle to check bg-color
    if (circ.classList.contains('green')) {
        y += '1';
    } else {
        y += '0';
    }
});

if ( y.indexOf("0") > -1 )  { // are there red circles?
    console.log('dont do anything'); //yes there are
} else {
    console.log('run submit button css change function'); // no there aren't. go ahead and run a function to change submit css here
}
```

---

Toggling css classes instead of inline styles is cleaner and shorter too if you have a lot of circles which results in better site performance.

Comment: you may correct your code [better test before also] .. classList apply directly to element not style

Comment: I also don't agree with your other snippet, you will return true or false for each one ... but the idea is to return true if ALL of them have the green class and false if not

Comment: @Temani The classList checks if all the circles has the class green or not and return true if they all do :https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/ubz6xvcf/. The OP can then write a new function somewhere else that changes the submit button css if the above returns true on all circle elements.

Comment: test your last code and you will see that you have 4 output for each element ... but we should have only one output, your logic is not correct in this case, we should loop through the elemens and not run a function for each one separately.

Comment: And the `return true/return false` are just for explanatory reasons. Some of the things he can replace the returns with is for example, run a coun that add 1 to a string if its true and 0 if its false. Then after the loop ends, check if the string has 0. If it does not have 0, change the submit button. That is one of the things he can do with the above codes. There are like a thousand things he can replace that with honestly.

Comment: Let me show you what I mean with another jsfiddle that doesnt use console.log

Comment: I know what you meant and I didn't say it's wrong, I said that I don't agree with this logic ;) forEach is not the suitable solution in this case [for me]

Comment: forEach does work for this. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/ubz6xvcf/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Btw, I managed to flip your reversed image in profile description with css just now. Cheers lol

Comment: again, I never said it's wrong or it doesn't work BUT it's not suitable. Your code is not efficient as for each element you will apply a test function and then you have to store each state for each one then you need to check if there is one that is not good. A lot of code and logic for an easy task. Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ubz6xvcf/3/. A simple for loop and I break it whenever I find a red class, no need to test all the element or run a function for each element and no need any complicated variable, a boolean one is enough.

Comment: That works beautifully. I see what you mean. Post that as an answer man. I'll upvote it.